# Modifying the list while using for comprehension in Scala

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I have a list that contains all possible deals between clients, and every sell-buy combination needs to be compared. With the comparison, another list need to be modified.

I have the following code:

```
def res(input_orders: List[Order], input_clients: List[Client]): List[Client] = {
  for {
    order1 <- input_orders
    order2 <- input_orders if check_order(order1, order2)
    firstClient = input_clients.find(_.name == order1.client)
    secondClient = input_clients.find(_.name == order2.client)
    tmp <- if (order1.operation == 's') {    
      input_clients.map { case `firstClient` => sell(firstClient.get, order1); case x => x }
      input_clients.map { case `secondClient` => buy(secondClient.get, order2); case x => x }
    } else {
      input_clients.map { case `firstClient` => buy(firstClient.get, order1); case x => x }
      input_clients.map { case `secondClient` => sell(secondClient.get, order2); case x => x }
    }
  } yield tmp
}
```

But it returns the list of clients as it is and does not modify it.

I suppose that the problem is in this "modification" block:

```
  input_clients.map { case `firstClient` => sell(firstClient.get, order1); case x => x }
  input_clients.map { case `secondClient` => buy(secondClient.get, order2); case x => x }
} else {
  input_clients.map { case `firstClient` => buy(firstClient.get, order1); case x => x }
  input_clients.map { case `secondClient` => sell(secondClient.get, order2); case x => x }
```

What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

Recall that the `map` function is *immutable* which means it doesn't do any modification to the datastructure but rather returns a new object which content has been updated.

In the block you're mentioning, the first calls of `map`are useless because the return value is never used. A proper way of achieving the task you initially wanted to do would be:

```
val order = order1.operation == 's'
input_clients.map {
  case `firstClient` => if (order) sell(firstClient.get, order1) else buy(firstClient.get, order1)
  case `secondClient` => if (order) buy(secondClient.get, order2) else sell(secondClient.get, order2)
  case x => x
}
```

Moreover, avoid using the `get` accessor of an `Option[T]` (imagine what would happen if the option was `None`). Prefer safer operations like pattern matching or `flatMap` / for-comprehension instead.